# Does testing for assumptions affect type I error?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, assumptions, bonferroni, type-i-and-ii-errors

I just performed simple simulation. Made two "populations" with different means and the same variance. Since I prepared them I know that they: are normal, differs in location and both have the same scale. Then I wrote simple script in R which 1000 times draws samples from the both populations, test them for normality (Shapiro-Wilk), for equal variances (F) and for difference (t). If the assumptions of t-test are met I run t-test.

Well, in fact I run all of them one by one, but combine the results with logical AND operator. So, if **IsNormal**(A) AND **IsNormal**(B) AND **VarsAreEqual**(A, B) AND **MeansAreDifferent**(A, B), then I count the result. Finally I divide number of TRUE values and divide it by the number of iterations. So, every test of assumption may fail. Shapiro-Wilk may falsely (they **ARE** normal) reject H0 as well as F test (they **HAVE** equal variances). And I don't get values near 0.05!

So, my question is: is this an example of the "multiple testing" phenomena (like multiple comparisons)? If so, what about testing for assumptions? Such testing is crucial as if the assumptions are not met, the quantiles of sampling distribution of a given test may be completely different than expected and so given results may be completely useless. But testing for the assumptions clearly changes the alpha. Am I correct?

Perhaps we should use corrections for alpha, like Bonferroni?

```r
data<- data.frame(populA=rnorm(1000, mean=1), populB=rnorm(1000, mean=3))

iternum <- 1000
alpha   <- 0.05
nsample <- 50
results <- array(FALSE, iternum);

for(i in 1:iternum) {
    sampA <- sample(data$populA, 30);
    sampB <- sample(data$populB, 30);

    result_t <- t.test(sampA, sampB)$p.value;
    result_F <- var.test(sampA, sampB)$p.value;
    result_normA <- shapiro.test(sampA)$p.value;
    result_normB <- shapiro.test(sampB)$p.value;

    results[i] <- (result_normA >= alpha) & (result_normB >= alpha) & 
                  (result_F >= alpha) & (result_t < alpha)
}
> 1-(mean(results))

[1] 0.158
```

Comment: Oh, I was too fast :) Of course, I know, that p.value of t-test WILL be near 0 as they really differ, so this doesn't affects my results. My questions concerns the tests that may fail - Shapiro and F.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking, the answer is *yes*, both type I and type II error rates are impacted by choosing tests on the basis of tests of assumptions.

This is pretty well established with testing of equality of variance (for which several papers point it out), and testing normality. It should be expected that it will be the case in general.

The advice is usually along the lines of "if you can't make the assumption without testing, better to simply act as if the assumption doesn't hold".

So, for example, if you're trying to decide between the equal-variance and Welch-type t-tests, by default use the Welch test (though under equal sample size it is robust to violations of that assumption).

Similarly, in moderately-small$^*$ samples, you may be better off using a permutation test for location by default than testing for normality and then using a t-test if you fail to reject (in large samples, the t-test is usually level-robust enough that it's not likely to be that big an issue in most cases, if the sample is also large enough that you're not concerned about impact on power). Alternatively, the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney has very good power compared to the t-test at the normal, and would often be a very viable alternative.

[If for some reason you need to test it would be best to be aware of the extent to which the significance level and power of the tests may be affected under either arm of any resulting choice the test of assumptions leads you to. This will depend on the particular circumstances; for example simulation can be used to help investigate the behavior in similar situations.]
*  (but not very small, since the discreteness of the test statistic will limit the available significance levels too much; specifically, at very small sample sizes the smallest possible significance level may be impractically large)

A reference (with a link to more) on testing heteroskedasticity when choosing between equal-variance-t vs Welch-t location tests is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/practically-speaking-how-do-people-handle-anova-when-the-data-doesnt-quite-mee/97120#97120).

I also have one for the case of testing normality before choosing between the t test and the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test (ref [3] [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121852/how-to-choose-between-t-test-or-non-parametric-test-e-g-wilcoxon-in-small-sampl/123389#123389)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Glen_b. It hit me after the course of statistics I participated in, where teacher told us: "always! test for compliance with assumptions". I agree with you, there are some points I can follow your advice, for example Welch test you've mentioned. Moreover I know that if the distribution is symmetric (not necessarily normal, it can be even uniform or has many modes), the CLT works for us very well and it's not neccesary to test for normality. But what about other assumptions - many of tests have them. I cannot just assume that I will always use nonparametric ones or

Comment: use Monte Carlo (bootstrapping or permutation) methods. Parametric regression, parametric ANOVA, parametric correlation and so on. Yes, indeed they are resistant to deviation from normality (CLT), but only for kurtosis and not for skewness, especially when there are "unbalanced" designs. Then... Should I always choose for nonparametrical or MC ones after I look at the scatterplot/boxplot/qq-plot? This is so "informal" that many of teachers will fail me during the exam calling it "reading tea leaves" :)

Comment: But even Wilcoxon is not a "pure" nonparametric test as it has underlying assumption about equality of scale parameters (tested with Ansari Bradley test) :( I'm totally lost. It seems that the main diagnostic tool is scatterplot, boxplot and histogram (or kernel density curve) with Q-Q plot. But what about formal side of testing for assumptions? There are other assumptions, for example about sphericity of covariance matrix, autocovariance, stationarity in time series analysis...

Comment: That's a lot of questions, I hardly know where to start.

Comment: Let's write the questions here: 1. as we already know such testing changes errors, how to agree this with advices of well skilled teachers, often PhD? They say clearly: "test it formally, plots and diagrams are only additional tools". 2. Avoid formal testing? Yes, somethimes CLT will do the job for us as well as bootstrapping, but not always (there are other types of assumptions). 3. Always choose the nonparametric tests? But even some of them are "semi-non-parametric" and somethimes it involves lack of power (not every test has such a good properties as Wilcoxon (power ~ 80% of t-Test).

Comment: ...and please, do not be angry with me for so many questions. This was very unpleasant discovery for me, now I'm totally lost. My teacher (on vacation now) says one, my practice says second. I asked those questions to another teacher and he told me: "leave the tests, watch only diagnostic plots when sample size > 25-30".

Comment: 1. (a) What's the PhD *in*? A PhD in one subject doesn't make one an authority in much at all;  (b) What is their justification for this procedure? If they can't provide a good reason to act that way, their expertise *should* be doubted  2. Seems to be no question here to respond to.  3. I didn't say always choose nonparametric tests; Welch isn't nonparametric, for example. It's about choosing tests that aren't badly affected by the assumptions you can't make.

Comment: I wasn't angry, just confounded. You were right to suggest that choosing a procedure based on diagnostics *also* carries problems (which is why I didn't suggest it!); I'll make an edit to my answer above to address why that's at least somewhat better in one sense.

Comment: 1. I was taught year ago by two PhD in statistics (econometry AFAIR). They said that only formal testing will ensure me that the assumption is met or not and that reading from diagrams is very rough and cannot stand as a formal justification. I cannot agree since I **see** the distribution isn't skewed and I know the CLT will do the job. Or I see strong skewness and choose the nonparametric test (although Wilcoxon is falling me down with its own assumption...). 3. Oh yes, you're right. Here we have a safe alternative, but this is just a one case. Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!

Comment: (I'd take this to chat if you had the reputation.) $\quad$ • Econometrics and statistics are not the same thing -- but even formally trained statisticians can be taught something that's not well justified, accept it anyway, and pass it on. Fortunately you didn't do the same. Hold onto that doubt - you shouldn't accept anything I can't justify either. $\quad$ • Beware; skewness isn't the only source of problems with non-normality. $\quad$ • Wilcoxon doesn't assume equal spread - *unless* you're only dealing with location-shift alternatives, you don't need that. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) 3. Bootstrapping, robust methods, Bayesian approaches can often be constructed that have better properties if the assumption is in doubt. At the very least one can check sensitivity to assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very very much Glen, you are the first person who tried to help me :) I will mark your first answer as accepted, but I don't know if it lock and prevent you from adding more information (references).

Comment: @Bastian it won't stop me from adding more information. Answers can be improved indefinitely (though eventually they become community wiki), it's part of what makes the stackexchange model so useful

Comment: @Bastian Curious what led to the unaccept 8 years down the track. Is there some way in which the answer is now inadequate and needs improvement? (I am not complaining about the choice to do so; you're free to unaccept as you see fit, but curious as to its cause after so long and wanting to see what you believe is needed to improve it.)

Comment: I'm sorry, it was by mistake. I unaccepted it initially (now reverted) because I misunderstood that the impact is by multiple testing, which of course cannot be, because the hypotheses are disconnected, and testing for, say, equal variances does nothing with testing for means. Now I realized you wrote about something else - about the fact, that it may affect the error rates not because of multiplicity of tests, but about the choice of different method, which is of course right. So testing for assumptions affects the type 1 and 2 errors totally by the choice of test DRIVEN by the assumptions.

Comment: And, frankly speaking, my entire question is wrong. It doesn't matter how many assumptions I test. What I got in the simulation was the error of joint testing on the assumptions, NOT the test of interest, which alpha level remains of course the same. If I test the assumptions and they are violated a bit, and instead of using a non-parametric (maybe weaker) test I will use the same parametric test but permuted (of similar power), almost nothing will actually change. I was wrong entirely in my own question. I should delete it to not misled others, believing the affection is via multiplicity!

Comment: Multiplicity of testing really does impact the combined rate of type I errors (the probability there's at least one type I error in the collection of tests). Whether that's important important or not is not particularly a statistical issue; in other contexts that's a matter for your and whoever your results are for. I maybe should cycle back to that point at the end of my answer. I don't think there's anything to gain from deleting this question; it's likely to prove useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought on this topic.

It's certainly true that when testing for assumptions with many different tests, you are going to end up with a higher than $\alpha$ type I error rates (where $\alpha$ is the significance level test for each individual test), just by standard multiple testing issues.

But when testing assumptions, often type I error is not as bad as a type II error! For example, if your data is not normal and you falsely reject, then you may proceed to use a more robust test, *which is (likely) still valid if the data is normal*. On the other hand, if you fail to reject but the data is not normal, then you falsely assume normality, leading to the known problems of invalid assumptions.

When doing multiple comparison procedures (i.e. Bonferroni, etc.), we are trying to preserve the type I error rate, at the cost of higher type II error rates. In regards to testing assumptions, that seems like a silly notion, given the higher costs of type II errors.

You can, of course, take this one step further and ask why we are using significance levels for tests of assumptions to start with, when it's really power we should be concerned about. If you did, I would agree with you, but I'm not ready to open that whole can of worms at the moment.