# Normality and homogeneity

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, t-test, heteroscedasticity

I have performed certain statistical tests (ANOVA, DMRT, t-test, etc.) assuming my data is normal as well as with homogeneous variance. Now my paper is almost accepted in a reputed journal, reviewer asked me,"Is your data normal and with homogeneous variance". On performing Shapiro-Wilk test I came to know that a part of my data (one out of four treatments, each treatment has three replicates) is not normal. Similarly, a part of my data does not have equal variance. What should be my reply to the reviewer? Do I have to analyse my data again?

P.S. I am not a statistician.

Comment: What's the sample size? I think that test is sensitive to sample size. Also, what does the skew (and kurtosis) look like? Did you look at histograms, q-q plots, etc.? It doesn't sound to me like your whole analysis has been invalidated by the one significant test among 4 treatments...

Comment: What did you test when you used Shapiro-Wilk?  Did you test the residuals?  What about other tests of normality?  ANOVA is robust against minor departures from normality.

Comment: How many observations did you have in the subgroup that you rejected normality for?

Comment: If the reviewer is asking the question, the implication is that you are not showing the data directly and perhaps over-focusing on significance tests, which is the tone of your question too. Showing normal probability plots as well as looking at Shapiro-Wilk tests is a way to try to satisfy everyone. You might even get ideas to improve your analyses.

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121852/a-principled-method-for-choosing-between-t-test-or-non-parametric-e-g-wilcoxon) gives a reference that clearly comes out against performing formal tests of assumptions (including of normality) when choosing a test. It gives links to posts with several references that make the same point about equality of variance (homogeneity of variance). There's some explanation in respect of homogeneity tests [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100934/does-testing-for-assumptions-affect-type-i-error/100941#100941).

Comment: There are many more posts on site relating to tests of assumptions that will be relevant.